# generate different random variable

Tags: matlab

I want to generate 5 different random variables, & I want also to satisfy other condition which is    N(rand1,rand2) =0 where N is 10-by-10 matrix that contains 0s & 1s.

This is the code that I wrote , it generate different random number , but I want to satisfy the other condition.

```
nb_sources=5;
nb_Des=5;

rand_nb= randperm(n,n);
    source = [rand_nb(1:nb_sources)]  ;
    distination=  [rand_nb(nb_sources+1:nb_sources+nb_Des)] ;
```

Comment: When you say random variables, you mean integer random numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested only in N(r1,r2)=0, you need to enumerate all these elements of N (lets say from from 1 to 30), generate 5 random numbers as rand(30,5,1) and pick up the indices. E.g. something like this

```
Nelem = 5;
[I,J] = find(N==0);
ind = randperm(size(I,1));
Res=[I(ind(1:Nelem)),J(ind(1:Nelem))];
```